# How to handle memory leaks in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I've just finished developing my first app in iOS. In the beginning it showed like 21 memory leaks. Now, after completion it showed 0 memory leaks
. I want to know how a memory leak occurs and how to handle it so that I can solve it myself if I get any in the future.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at using Instruments for such a thing:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started

This tutorial will show you how to use the most important features of the tool called Instruments that ships with Xcode. It allows you to check your code for performance issues, memory issues, reference cycles, and other problems.

In this tutorial you’re going to learn:

1. How to determine hot-spots in your code using the Time Profiler instrument in order to make your code more efficient, and
2. How to detect and fix memory management issues such as strong reference cycles in your code using the Allocations instrument.